# How to obtain a Cambodia tourist visa in Bangkok?

Tags: visas, cambodia, tourist-visas, bangkok

I've read that some people go to Khao San and pay about 20 USD to a travel agency in order to obtain a tourist visa for Cambodia. That's ok with me, but I don't know the exact date when I'll enter Cambodia, because I will travel through Thailand and Laos before entering Cambodia. Is that a problem? Is any travel agency ok or would you recommend a particular one?

EDIT:

I should have mentioned straight away that I mean to enter Cambodia from Laos.

Answer (score 5):

You can get a tourist visa on-arrival in Cambodia at all airports and most main land border points with Thailand, so you don't need to obtain one in advance. If you *still* want to get one in advance, the easiest way is to apply online for an 'e-visa', the [details for which are listed on the Cambodian Ministry of Foreign Affairs website](http://www.mfaic.gov.kh/evisa/). Getting a visa in advance isn't necessary, just that you don't have to wait in a queue with the unwashed masses of other backpackers to get your visa. In my opinion, getting a visa in advance is not worth the extra fee you pay for processing, at all.

Note that [Cambodia and Thailand have historically had border disputes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cambodian%E2%80%93Thai_border_dispute), although at the moment this is not a concern.

Comment: Well, I don't know if that's true, but I've read that when you arrive from Laos to Cambodia  sometimes is not possible to get the visa on arrival. In fact, in the link you have published say that there is no VISA on arrival on Stung Treng.

Comment: Where were you considering entering Cambodia from? I assumed Thailand because you asked about Bangkok.

Comment: No, sorry, Bangkok is the first city we stay in this trip. We will cross through south of Laos. After some days in Si Phan Don (Laos) we will go to Kratie (Cambodia). I believe the only checkpoint in this area is Stung Treng, so we will have to stamp our passports here.

Comment: Okay, so please clarify that in the question.

Comment: Cambodian Immigration authorities now fingerprint visitors on arrival and departure (not anymore at Poi Pet crossing). These fingerprints may well find their way to your country's authorities or any other agency that cares to buy them. If you object to that, bribe the official (US$1-2 should be enough if you're gutsy enough to try) - from wikitravel